# Including a start and end node to a graphviz digraph

Tags: python, pandas, graphviz

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
Start Activity  End Activity    Duration
0   a   b   2.13
1   b   c   1.29
2   b   d   1.54
3   d   e   3.39
4   d   g   3.42
5   e   f   1.75
6   e   g   1.11
7   f   g   2.25
8   f   h   2.29
9   g   e   2.59
10  g   f   1.68
11  g   h   2.22
```

I have been able to draw a directed followed graph using the code below:

```
Z = graphviz.Digraph(format='jpeg')

Z.attr(rankdir='LR')
Z.attr('node', shape='circle', color='red', style='filled', fontsize='20', fontcolor='white')
Z.attr('edge', arrowhead='vee', arrowtail='inv', color='green', fontcolor='blue')

max_node = 5
max_case_id = sortnewtime2['Duration'].max()

nodelist2 = []
for idx, row in sortnewtime2.iterrows():
    node11, node22, weight2 = [str(i) for i in row]
    
    if node11 not in nodelist2:
        Z.node(node11)
        nodelist2.append(node22)
    if node22 not in nodelist2:
        Z.node(node22)
        nodelist2.append(node22)
        
    Z.edge(node11, node22, label = weight2, penwidth=str(float(weight2)/max_case_id*max_node)) 

Z
```

and with this output

[image: Graphviz Output]

However, I want to ask if it is possible to insert a start and stop node to show where the process starts and stop?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you append 2 rows to the data frame - start in end activity with nothing in start activity and zero duration; end in start activity with nothing in end activity and zero duration. In `iterrows` you test for those conditions and create nodes appropriately?

Comment: Thanks Robin. I have tried it but I wasn't able to get it. I still haven't found a solution to this. But I will keep trying to figure it out.